# How to change project root directory name of maven project

Tags: java, angularjs, maven

As I working on maven project I wanted to change my root directory of my project
which is already named as GDPR and it has to be changed as AUDIT

[image]

As shown above in image, it is displaying GDPR in URL and tab name But, I have to change it as AUDIT

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"

```
    version="3.1">
<display-name>AUDIT</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<listener>

    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>

</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<filter>
    <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Above is web.xml, which I already changed as AUDIT in display name tag But, still it is not changing.

Comment: What kind of project is this? Do you have a `web.xml`?

Comment: yes, I have web.xml and this project is a maven project.

Comment: You can see my web.xml above